# Is there a better way in particular to iterate over all valid (positive) entries of a sparse matrix using scipy.sparse?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, nan

I'm just trying to understand the advantages of using `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` here. I know it speeds up the computation of huge, sparse matrices at a whole (e.g SVD) but does it have a better way to iterate over all valid, positive entries in it? Also, is it preferred to calculate row/column averages with `np.array` or `csr_matrix`?

```py
from numpy import np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from random import shuffle

# sparse matrix with missing values = 0
S = csr_matrix((np.linspace(1,29,1000), (shuffle(np.arange(1000)),shuffle(np.arange(1000)))), 
               shape=(1000,1000))
# sparse matrix with missing values = NaN
A = S.toarray()
A = (A==0)*np.nan + A

def dosomething():
    dosomething

# iterate over all valid entries
m,n = A.shape
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
         if not np.isnan(A[i,j]):
             dosomething()
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        if S[i,j]>0:
            dosomething()

# calculate column averages
A_col_avg = np.nansum(A,axis=0) / (m - np.sum(np.isnan(A),axis=0))
A = A - A_col_avg
S_col_avg = np.sum(S,axis=0) / np.sum((S>0),axis=0)
S = S - S_col_avg
```

Comment: `csr` is good for matrix mutiplication when sparsity ls less than 10%.  Row and column sums are actually performed with matrix multiplication.  So are many indexing operations.   Element iteration, even with a focus on nonzero values is generally slower.  They can also be useful when the dense equivalent would be too big for memory.

Comment: The best way to iterate element-wise through an array in python is not to.